# How to change my regex to match/replace on 2nd, 3rd, ... words, but not on first one?

Tags: java, regex

The task must be solved using regular expressions without using container classes.

Input: text (may consist of Latin and Cyrillic letters, does not contain `_`)

Output: source text, but precede all repeated words with an underscore `_`

To consider a word as a sequence containing only letters (all other characters are not included in the word).
Create a static convert method that converts input to output.

Method to complete:

```
public static String convert (String input) {
    ...
}
```

Input example:

```
This is a test
And this is also a test
And these are also tests
test
Это тест
Это также тест
И это также тесты
```

Output example:

```
This _is _a _test
_And this _is _also _a _test
_And these are _also tests
_test
_Это _тест
_Это _также _тест
И это _также тесты
```

My attempt:

```java
public static void convert(String input) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\b\\w+\\b)(?=[\\s\\S]*\\b\\1\\b[\\s\\S]*\\b\\1\\b)", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
        String res = p.matcher(input+" "+input).replaceAll("_$1");
        res = res.substring(0, res.length() - 1 - p.matcher(input).replaceAll("_$1").length());
        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

My output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdhdS.png)

```
This _is _a _test
_And this _is _also _a test
_And these are _also tests
_test
_Это _тест
_Это _также _тест
И это _также тесты
```

Word "test" in second row without "_" but i need "_test"

Comment: I just copied and ran your code. It produces expected output but in case of special character words it's appending  _ everywhere `This _is _a _test
_And this _is _also _a _test
_And these are _also tests
_test
_Э_т_о _т_е�?_т
_Э_т_о _т_а_кж_е _т_е�?_т
_И _�?_т_о _т_а_кж_е _т_е�?_т_ы`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may collect all repeated words and then prepend them with `_`:

```
// Java 9+
String s = "This is a test\nAnd this is also a test\nAnd these are also tests\ntest\nЭто тест\nЭто также тест\nИ это также тесты";
String rx = "(?sU)\\b(\\w+)\\b(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)";
String[] results = Pattern.compile(rx).matcher(s).results().map(MatchResult::group).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?U)\\b(?:" + String.join("|", results) + ")\\b", "_$0"));

// Java 8
String s = "This is a test\nAnd this is also a test\nAnd these are also tests\ntest\nЭто тест\nЭто также тест\nИ это также тесты";
String rx = "(?sU)\\b(\\w+)\\b(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)";
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(rx).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?U)\\b(?:" + String.join("|", matches) + ")\\b", "_$0"));
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/2rae4F) and the [second snippet demo](https://ideone.com/jfSMQh). Output:

```
This _is _a _test
_And this _is _also a _test
And these are _also tests
test
_Это _тест
_Это _также тест
И это _также тесты
```

Note I replaced `[\s\S]` workaround construct with the `.` combined with the `s` DOTALL embedded flag option (so that `.` could match line breaks, too), used Java 9+ `.results()` method to return all matches and built the final pattern out of the found matches joined with `|` OR alternation operator.

**Details**

- `(?sU)\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)`:

  - `(?sU)` - an embedded DOTALL (makes `.` match linebreaks, too) and UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS (makes all shorthands Unicode aware) flag options
  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `(\w+)` - Group 1: 1+ word chars, letters, digits or `_`s
  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `(?=.*\b\1\b)` - immediately to the right, there must be any 0+ chars, as many as possible, followed with the same value as in Group 1 as a whole word.
- `(?U)\\b(?:" + String.join("|", results) + ")\\b"`: this pattern will look like `(?U)\b(?:test|is|Это|тест|также)\b`

  - `(?U)` - an embedded UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag option
  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `(?:test|is|Это|тест|также)` - a non-capturing alternation group
  - `\b` - word boundary

The replacement is `_$0` for the second regex as the `_` is appended to the whole match value, `$0`.

Comment: Thanks for the help and clarification. but I have an error: The method results () is undefined for the type Matcher and The method map(MatchResult::group) is undefined for the type Matcher

Comment: @VanuaAunav They are supported from Java 9. Try the second code snippet for Java 8.